# Unable to install python 3.0 sdk for couchbase

Tags: python, couchbase, python-3.8

I’m unable to install python sdk 3.0 on windows 10 with python 3.8 and latest pip version. Followed the instructions here. https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/3.0/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html
I ran the command on cmd prompt and it finished with error

ERROR: Failed building wheel for couchbase

Failed to build couchbase

ERROR: Could not build wheels for couchbase which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

How should I go about the installation?

Thanks

Kashyap